# how to use a field value from access query into vba code

Tags: vba, email, ms-access-2010

[image]

Hi,I'm trying to make a Access macro, what sends mails to persons.

This mails exist in a field "MailField" from a Query "Query1". So I'm trying to loop into all rows and send mails using the "MailField" with the corresponding value of row i as "Message":

Example: mail to "mail2@123.com" With a message "value of field a in row 2".

```
Function makroabc()
On Error GoTo makroabc_Err

For i = "first Raw" To "mumber of data in the query"

    If (Eval("Hour(Now()) Between 11 And 16")) Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
        DoCmd.SendObject , "", "", "Mail from row i", "", "", "Subject", "Message", False, ""
    End If

Next i

makroabc_Exit:
    Exit Function

makroabc_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume makroabc_Exit

End Function
```

What can i input instead of  "Mail from row i" ?

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To use a value from a query in VBA, don't use `DoCmd.OpenQuery`. Open a **Recordset** instead.

E.g. to send to all recipients in the query, loop over the recordset:

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim subj as String

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Query1")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    subj = "Hello " & rs![field b]
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , rs!Mailfield, , , subj, "Message", False
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Note though that Outlook may display a security warning.

Comment: Thank you a lot , and how can i express the corresponding field a.value of the corresponding mail  as  "Subject"?

Comment: Now it works without error ,Nevertheless i can't receive the Email. any Idea?

Comment: @user3569647: no, that can have many reasons, one would need to look at your installation to analyze it. And it really is a new question.